# Use HTTPS for Kubernetes nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, https, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, nginx-ingress

I want to use HTTPS for my Kubernetes on Azure (AKS).
For that I use nginx-ingress (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md#azure).
All of the ressources, which I created by this tutorial, are using the namespace ingress-nginx. That's why I continue using this namespace instead of default.
My Ingress is working like expected. Now I want to use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

For that I created an CSR:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key -out example.csr -subj "/CN=domain.com"
```

I send the CSR to a signing provider (QuoVadis) who send me the following files back:

- domain_com(chain).crt
- domain_com.crt
- QuoVadis_Global_SSL_ICA_G2.crt
- QuoVadis_Root_CA_2.crt

I'm a little bit confused because in all tutorials I found only one crt is mentioned. The chain looks like an combination of all other three files. That's why I continued with the chain:

```
sudo kubectl create secret tls ssl-secret-test --cert domain_com(chain).crt --key private.key -n ingress-nginx
```

I added the secret to my ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.com
    secretName: ssl-secret-test
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app2(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app2-service
          servicePort: 80
```

My deployments app1 & app2 are not available by the domain anymore. If I use the IP it is still working:

**domain.com/app1:**

*404 Not Found - openresty/1.15.8.1*

**52.xxx.xxx.xx/app1:**

*Hello World*

In both cases, I still get the warning of an unsecured connection. 
Here an overview of my services:

```
$ sudo kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP                                  PORT(S)                      AGE
default         kubernetes                       ClusterIP      10.0.0.1       <none>                                       443/TCP                      57d
ingress-nginx   app1-service                     NodePort       10.0.229.109   <none>                                       80:31343/TCP                 22h
ingress-nginx   app2-service                     NodePort       10.0.175.201   <none>                                       80:31166/TCP                 22h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx                    LoadBalancer   10.0.40.172    52.xxx.xxx.xx                                80:32564/TCP,443:32124/TCP   22h
kube-system     healthmodel-replicaset-service   ClusterIP      10.0.233.181   <none>                                       25227/TCP                    5d10h
kube-system     heapster                         ClusterIP      10.0.214.146   <none>                                       80/TCP                       57d
kube-system     kube-dns                         ClusterIP      10.0.0.10      <none>                                       53/UDP,53/TCP                57d
kube-system     kubernetes-dashboard             ClusterIP      10.0.160.230   <none>                                       80/TCP                       57d
kube-system     metrics-server                   ClusterIP      10.0.170.103   <none>                                       443/TCP                      57d

$ sudo kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME            HOSTS              ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress   domain.com         52.xxx.xxx.xx   80, 443   37m

$ sudo kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE       NAME                       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
ingress-nginx   app1                       2         2         2            2           22h
ingress-nginx   app2                       2         2         2            2           22h
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller   1         1         1            1           57d
kube-system     coredns                    2         2         2            2           58d
kube-system     coredns-autoscaler         1         1         1            1           58d
kube-system     heapster                   1         1         1            1           5d10h
kube-system     kubernetes-dashboard       1         1         1            1           58d
kube-system     metrics-server             1         1         1            1           58d
kube-system     omsagent-rs                1         1         1            1           58d
kube-system     tunnelfront                1         1         1            1           58d
```

What I'm doing wrong?

## Update with cert-manager

I followed the following tutorial:

https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html

and confirmed everything by the example test-resources.yaml.

Now I followed the steps for setting up a CA ISSUER.

```
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: domain-com
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretName: domain-com-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: ca-issuer
    kind: ClusterIssuer
  commonName: domain.com
  organization:
  - QuoVadis
  dnsNames:
  - domain.com
  - www.domain.com
-----
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: ca-issuer
  namespace: default
spec:
  ca:
    secretName: ssl-secret-test
```

But it seems that it is not working:

```
$ kubectl describe certificate domain-com
...
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2019-09-12T07:48:19Z
    Message:               Certificate does not exist
    Reason:                NotFound
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
  Not After:               2021-09-11T07:46:00Z
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                 From          Message
  ----     ------          ----                ----          -------
  Warning  IssuerNotReady  8s (x9 over 4h51m)  cert-manager  Issuer ca-issuer not ready
```

And on the troubleshooting page, I found an additional uncertainty:

```
$ kubectl --namespace cert-manager get secret cert-manager-webhook-webhook-tls
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "cert-manager-webhook-webhook-tls" not found
```

Comment: so just out of curiosity is their a reason you dont try use a solution like cert-manager as i beleive cert m-manager is the one that requires you in the tls section to set a host https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html, let me know if this is what you are looking for an i will write up a full answer

Comment: I also read about cert-manager. I thought it is a tool like HELM/Tiller. Useful but not required. This is the first cluster I set up. That's why I wanted to do all from scratch without these tools. So that I get a deep understanding of how everything is working. Anyway, I take a look at cert-manager. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I answered in the comments but will just add the Answer here:

Cert Manager is the easiest way to handle TLS with nginx ingress, after setting it up here https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/getting-started/install/kubernetes.html when you define your ingress it would look similar to:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" <-- This is very important to define which ingress controller to use
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging <-- defines the cert manager issuer
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.com
    secretName: ssl-secret-test
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app1-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app2(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app2-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Cert manager will then setup the TLS for your service

Comment: I edit my question. CA Issuer is the right one or am I wrong? And do you see anything which I do wrong?

Comment: question is there a reason you dont use lets encrypt?

Comment: Specification by my company :/

Comment: Just asking as I havent honestly used a signed certificate with cert manager yet

Comment: Do you maybe have an answer to why I still can access the ingress via IP and get a not found by domain?

Comment: That could possible be due to your DNS routing?

Comment: I think either we move this to a chat or ask another question on the DNS routing else this will get flagged\